# Скачивание картинки base64 из img

Tags: javascript, изображения, img

Есть тег `img`, в нём в `src` картинка base64, как её можно загрузить на компьютер пользователя (не тайно, можно и с окном выбора пути), к примеру, при клике на кнопку?

Также у картинки при сохранении имя - это нечто в base64, как её сохранять с нормальным именем?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать [аттрибут `download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download), хотя не [работает в браузерах IE, Safari, и Opera mini.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download)

```html
<a download="image.png" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
  Скачать картинку
</a>
```

Есть еще одно решение, которое работает во всех браузерах: посылать картинку от сервера, с таким HTTP header:

```
Content-Disposition:attachment;
```

Comment: А если от сервера посылать картинку, то как имя поменять?

Comment: @Vlmake С HTTP header `filename`, например `Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="image.jpg"`.

Comment: Спасибо,  большое. Только вот, если картинка base64 то как её от сервера передать !?!?!

Comment: Можно конвертировать между base64 и двойчними данными